# How to jump the line of breakpoint in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

for example, i create a breakpoint at line 22,to just create a mark there

[Add a breakpoint at line 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIsDg.png)

and while im coding, i want to jump to my mark line, for this breakpont is line 22,
is there any shortcut to jump to breakpoint line there?

ctrl+G simply jumps to a line but not my breakpoint

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the shortcut for this:

```
{
  "key": "",
  "command": "editor.debug.action.goToNextBreakpoint"
}
```

To do this, first go to the [The Keyboard Shortcuts editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings), and search goToNextBreakpoint, and add your preferred shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to enhance workflow with setting up **Go to Next Breakpoint** as alternative `F3` key action, which is by default assigned to **Find Next** command. Finding next occurrence of searched word is obviously quite important but we can assign `F3` to both commands with also declaring `When Expression`.

1. `CTRL+K` `CTRL+S` (Open Keyboard Shortcuts window)
2. paste `editor.debug.action.goToNextBreakpoint` to find Next breakpoint command
3. set keybinding to `f3` key (press `F3` and `ENTER`)
4. type `"f3"` In search field to list all commands using that key
5. select **Debug: Go to Next Breakpoint** command
6. `CTRL+K` `CTRL+E` (Changing When Expression)
7. Type: `editorFocus && breakpointsExist && !findWidgetVisible`
8. select **Find Next** command
9. `CTRL+K` `CTRL+E` (Changing When Expression)
10. Change default When expression to: `editorFocus && findWidgetVisible`

[image: Next Breakpoint in VS Code F3 Key]

Answer (score 0):

1. press ctrl+p and search Keyboard Shortcuts
   [image]
2. search breakpoint and set Go To Next Breakpoint. I have set the key on F4
   [image]